# Run system command from a self made html file

Tags: html, perl

I wrote a script in perl that creates a html file. I want to put in the html file a link that will run a different perl script. Is it possible to do so, and if so, what is the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use `CGI`? Generally, HTML cannot run a script, it can link to a URL. There can be a script associated with the URL on a server, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it using Javascript. I have found this code that calls a shell script. It wouldn't be difficult to modify it: http://www.itjungle.com/mpo/mpo052302-story01.html. (Credits to Shannon O'Donnell, text writter).

Comment: Thanks, maybe I hadn't mentioned it, but I'm looking for something in unix environment.

Comment: Is there a possibility to do so with a PHP script?